# Odd mark at the top of the screen of my new LG V30

Tags: screen, lg

I just got a LG V30, and noticed an odd mark at the top of my screen:

[image]

I'm guessing this is some kind of factory defect. Does anyone know if indicates deeper flaws in the screen? Considering I mostly have a black theme, it's usually invisible. I just don't want this to lead to other problems down the road.

There doesn't appear to be any kind of responsiveness issues in the area when I touch it, so it's not problematic in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I have the same type of defect on my LG V30 but it's on the bottom right corner of the screen
.  LG wanted me to send in my phone for repair, they said it would take 2 weeks, and would not offer a loaner phone in the meantime.  Decided to check with Verizon, and they are sending me a replacement phone by end of week.  Love this phone, and happy that it's a simple swap process.

Answer (score 0):

I took it into a Bell store (the carrier I bought the phone under).

The rep confirmed that it's a manufacturer defect, and was convinced that it will only get worse. I'm getting it swapped out.